# How do you install autopep8 into python 3x on a Mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, autopep8

I have a Mac and have installed the latest version of Python 3.x, and I downloaded/installed autopep8, but it got installed into the Python 2 directory.  I need autopep8 to be installed on the Python 3 directory. Can that be done?

$ pip install autopep8
$ autopep8 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (1.4.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
python3 -m pip install autopep8
```

Works on High Sierra with Python3 official installer, post-install script `Install Certificates.command` should be run afterward.